# The vertical line between the top navigation texts flickrs while hovering

Tags: html, css

While hovering the vertical line between the texts in the top navigation link, it keeps flickering & the CSS shows a referencing to a "hover" tag which is something that I'm not aware of.

Need help to stop that flickering behavior.

Site URL: http://www.catholic-collectibles.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, the lines "move" because of the padding that is applied when a user invokes the [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) (*<sup>Click the link to read more</sup>*) css selector.

On **line 122** of `topNav.css` you'll find this:

```
.navigation-container .top-cat:hover, .navigation-container .hover .top-cat {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    padding: 12px 12px 16px;
}
```

If you comment out that `padding`, the behavior will change.

**Example:**

```
.navigation-container .top-cat:hover, .navigation-container .hover .top-cat {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    /* padding: 12px 12px 16px; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove padding:

```
.navigation-container .top-cat:hover, .navigation-container .hover .top-cat{ padding:0;}
```